# How to check TCP half-open connections?

Tags: linux, tcp

Is there a quick way (command) to display all [TCP half-open](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_half-open) connections on a Linux server ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look for connections with state SYN_SENT or SYN_RCVD. I would use `ss -a | grep ^SYN` to see those connections.